# Show Items and related SubItems on the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, tree

I have a vba Array of items in column 1 and items they feed in column 2.
I want to have a clean visual way to illustrate a "branching" effect on the spreadsheet but I'm at a loss on what the best method would be.

So this question is more of "What is the best method to use" kinda thing.

Just to visualize though, let's say my array looks like this:
(Col1 and Col2 separated by a space)

```
Array1:
PowerStrip1   TV
PowerStrip1   DVDPlayer
PowerStrip2   Soundbar
```

I want to have them look something like this on the excel spreadsheet:

```
PowerStrip1
          |---> TV
          |---> DVDPlayer
PowerStrip2
          |---> Soundbar
```

Perhaps not the neatest way of showing it but you get the just. What would be the best method of achieving this look in a clean way?

Comment: There really is no "best way" as it all depends on what you plan on doing with it afterwards. Visually, in its most simple form, I would make the first column span the rows of all the child rows, (like this: https://i.imgur.com/JOgN592.png ) but if you need to track ID values as well, this is going to get complex, but if it's just a report, it's fairly simple. Excel may or may not be the right tool for this. You may also want to look into using pivot tables as it has some of this functionality built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pivot Table` is your friend in this. Select your data range then insert `Pivot Table` and arrange like below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment on @Harun24HR, so adding this as new answer

After creating a pivot table as mentioned by @Harun24HR, Try the following

1. In pivot table fields, click on the drop down available in Items field and select field setting. This will open a pop up
2. On subtotals & filters,  select radio button besides "None"
3. Now go to layout & print
4. Have the radio button beside "show items label in outline form checked
5. Now  and untick the check box below them

I believe this will give the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, Harun24HR provided a perfectly good solution but I also wanted to share a different solution I came up with that displayed the information in more of a Tree-View format just in case it helps anyone else.

Lets say the Sheet name is "Summary", and the range of information to be used is A2:B200.
Assume the "Parent" information is in column "A" and the "Child" information is in column "B".

Also, you need to go to the Developer Tab -> Insert -> Active X Controls -> More Controls -> Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0. This is the TreeView control which will show our information.

I changed the name of the TreeView control to "tv" for simplicity.

See code below:

```
Sub TreeViewStuff()
'Using TreeView Nodes to populate  the power sources summary
'Clear pre-existing nodes
Dim arr as variant
Dim str as string
Dim i as integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes.Clear
'Copy range into an array
arr = Sheets("Drop Downs").Range("A2:B200")
'The first column of the array contains the parents, lets add them as keys
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    str = ""
    'Add the parent
    Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes.Add Key:=arr(i, 1), Text:=arr(i, 1)
    'Expand the node
    Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes(Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes.Count).Expanded = True
    Err.Clear
Next i
'The second column will contain the kids, lets add them
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    str = ""
    'Add the kids
    Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes.Add arr(i, 1), tvwChild, arr(i, 2), arr(i, 2)
    'Expand the node
    Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes(Sheets("Summary").tv.Nodes.Count).Expanded = True
    Err.Clear
Next i
End Sub
```

The TreeView approach can give a "Dotted Line" illustration between the parent and child nodes which was something I wanted to show. Again thanks for the help!